# Python requests getting 403 but on mobile device works fine

Tags: python, python-requests

When requesting an HTML page in Python, I get a 403 forbidden response every time.

```
import requests
url = 'https://shop.rewe.de/mydata/login'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

>>> result.status_code
403
```

When I use the iOs app, for example "Rest", I just send GET with the same domain and no other additional settings and get a 200 OK response.
I don't know what the problem is when I run this in Python.

Edit:
This shows the metric within the rest app. When searching for the protocol I found the h2 or simply http/2 protocol. I think this is the problem. Postman and also the requests lib do not support this.

[image]

Comment: I would try this in postman or something similar which should show you what is going on.

Comment: I get a 403 using curl from my Desktop.  Do you have cookies for this web site in your iOS browser?

Comment: I think the problem is related to the Cloudflare redirect. The page prompts to enable Java and another point is that they want http/2 enabled.

Comment: I searched around and found out what the problem is. The real problem is definitely the cloudflare redirect but what is cloudflare doing? I searched around for a while and found out that the real problem is that they are proving the TLS handshake from the browser. Without it, it would be hard to bypass Cloudflare's TLS protection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed the cipher of the request session. Temporarily it works. I do not know how long ...

```
url = 'https://shop.rewe.de/mydata/login'

import ssl
import requests

from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
from requests.packages.urllib3.util import ssl_

CIPHERS = (
    'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA'
)


class TlsAdapter(HTTPAdapter):

    def __init__(self, ssl_options=0, **kwargs):
        self.ssl_options = ssl_options
        super(TlsAdapter, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, *pool_args, **pool_kwargs):
        ctx = ssl_.create_urllib3_context(ciphers=CIPHERS, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, options=self.ssl_options)
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(*pool_args,
                                       ssl_context=ctx,
                                       **pool_kwargs)


session = requests.session()
adapter = TlsAdapter(ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1)
session.mount("https://", adapter)

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0',
}
try:
    r = session.request('GET', url, headers=headers)
    print(r)
except Exception as exception:
    print(exception)
```